# How to modify multiple elements at a time in C?

Tags: c, arrays

Say I got an array

```
unsigned char digit[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
```

Yet I want to modify part of the array, make the array become something like:

```
{0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

Enumerate every element I want to modify and alter them might take some effort. Especially when there's a large amount of elements I want to change. I know in some languages like Python I may do something using a single line of code:

```
a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
a[4:] = [0, 0, 0, 0]
//a: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

So I wonder, is there a similar way to do that in C?

Comment: There is a way to do it in one line of code but I would not recommend doing it this way: `memset(&digit[4], 0, sizeof(digit) - (4 * sizeof(digit[0])));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are fewer possibilities in C, but in case of an `unsigned char` and setting its values to zero you could use [`memset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset):

```
memset(&digit[4], 0, 4);
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/efIS4t)

Comment: In this case it solves my question, thank you!
But since you said _possibilities_, I wonder if there's some other ways?
Like what if I want to change `digit` to `{0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 9, 17, 0}`, that is, alter it with several different value.

Comment: @AmarthGûl C99 standard does not allow this, but gcc has a nice extension that could be used with `memcpy`. [Here is a demo](https://ideone.com/NxN1H1).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight why wouldn't C99 allow that?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Oops, I thought this was an extension, but it's actually part of C99. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 3):

One options is that you could write a subroutine that would implement the interface that other languages provide "under the cover".  You'll probably want to educate yourself on 'VARARGS' to make it take a variable number of arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Others have already mentioned setting the array elements to a single value using `memset`, as a part of your follow up question you asked if some elements can be set to certain values like `{1, 2, 3, 4}`.

You can use `memcpy` here to achieve that. Since your type here is `unsigned char` I will keep that, but in general this method can be used for any type.

```
memcpy(&digit[4], ((unsigned char[4]){1, 2, 3, 4}), 4 * sizeof(unsigned char));
```

You can see the demo [here](https://ideone.com/nVmLZU).

Comment: The `sizeof(unsigned char)` is unnecessary since a) `sizeof` returns the size in `char`s and, b) `memcpy` copies the given number of `char`s (bytes).

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I agree with the comment that it is unnecessary but I wanted to make the statement general across types. I have also mentioned in the answer that this method can be used for any type. I had a feeling that OP wouldn't know how to extend it to other types (not trying to be disrespectful but careful).

Answer (score 0):

I think that maybe not the shortest but something you can easy do is just:

```
digit[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};   %Having this

a=the number in your vector you want to start making ceros;
n=the lenght of digit;
for(i=a;i=n;i++)
{
    digit[n]=0;
}
```

Is just a way I think you could use.
If you want to change an specific one just

```
b=position;
digit[b]=c; %Where c is the number you want to put in there.
```

I hope it works for you, good luck.

Comment: I think I did, maybe I understood something wrong, can I ask you why are you asking?

Comment: If it's because of the variable n that you can know with the function sizeof(), I think it's because of that. But correct me if it's not that.

Comment: This answer describes the method the OP is _specifically_ trying to avoid.